# Из RichTextBox в массив

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно ввести в программу данные такого вида:

login:password:id

login2:password2:id2

И т.д. Проблема в том, что в textbox данные нужно вводить только в строчку. 
Поэтому я решил использовать RichTextBox. Не подскажите, как записать данные из RichTextBox в массив string?

Comment: "В TextBox данные нужно вводить только в строчку". То есть свойства Multiline у TextBox вы предпочитаете не замечать?

Comment: Далее. Вопрос поставлен не верно. Здесь не играет роли, используете ли вы RichTextBox, TextBox или Label, Вам необходимо разделить некую входную строку на массив подстроки по ключевому элементу. В этом Вам поможет метод String.Split()

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Вы путаете `WinForms` c `WPF`. У `TextBox`из `WPF` нету `Multiline` свойства. Но делается там также, довольно просто, указав как минимум `AcceptsReturn="True"`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а, верно. Не заметил WPF в тегах

Comment: @EvgeniyZ для пароля лучше использовать Passwordbox

Comment: @Сергей А это уже другая история. В данном случае я просто поправил человека, не более...

Answer (score 1):

Весь текст из RichTextBox можно считать в строку:

```
string richText = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

При необходимости можно сделать массив:

```
string [] lines = richText.Split(new[]{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: При WPF MVVM подходе нельзя использовать richTextBox1 напрямую, нужно работать с моделью.

Comment: @Сергей А где в вопросе упоминается MVVM?

Comment: WPF это всегда MVVM, если конечно нет цели сделать фигню.

Comment: @Сергей не соглашусь. Есть и другие подходы, например, Elmish

Comment: В любом случае к вопросу это не имеет отношения. Код можно адаптировать к любому подходу